# Using Struts with SpringSource dm server gives Http Status 503 error

Tags: java, spring, struts, osgi, springsource-dm-server

I developed an enterprise application using spring, struts and hibernate, now I want to transfer it to work with OSGi dm server.

I found a book "Pro SpringSource dm server" where the author has explained a way to migrate WAR to OSGi bundles. I successfully migrated the application given in book.

The first step of migration says that remove the lib folder in WEB-INF directory and import all the relevant packages. I did the same. Application has been successfully deployed in the dm server.

But when I tried to connect to URL it is giving me the error:

SpringSource dm Server - Error report

HTTP Status 503 - Servlet action is currently unavailable

type:  Status report 
message:  Servlet action is currently unavailable

### description:  The requested service (Servlet action is currently unavailable) is not currently available.

What could be the reason for this?

I am out of clues to solve this issue. Can you pass any help you may have.

Thanks in anvance.

Comment: What does the server log say about error when deploying the WAR?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the WAR didn't deploy properly. The container seems to have have some idea that the webapp/servlet is there, but because it didn't start up correctly, it's not available.

Check your logs carefully, make sure dmServer indicates correct startup of the war and its servlets.